# How to remove redundant data in table from SQL query with join in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, join

CONTROLLER:

```
class adminpanel extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_database');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['h'] = $this->login_database->load_orders();  
        $this->load->view('admin_page', $data);
    }

}
```

MODEL:

```
public function load_orders(){
    $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->from('orders');
    $this->db->join('order_detail', 'orders.serial = order_detail.orderid');
    $this->db->join('customers', 'orders.customerid = customers.serial');
    $this->db->order_by('date','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
        return $result;     
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
      <tbody>  
         <tr>  
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Delivery Time</td> 
            <td>Meal Name</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>  
            <td>Customer Name</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Location</td> 
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Payment Method</td>
         </tr>  
         <?php  foreach ($h as $row)  { ?>
            <tr>  
               <td><?php echo $row->date;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->time;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->prodname;?></td>   
               <td><?php echo $row->quantity;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->phone;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->location;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row->payment;?></td>
            </tr>  
         <?php } ?>  
      </tbody>  
   </table>
```

The table being returned has so much redundant data e.g. one customer has ordered many different meals. it shows same customer name over and over for his meals which he has ordered. How do i eliminate this and show in the table??

Please help.

Comment: @CodeGodie.. the edited version seems to be the same??

Comment: hi gugz. Actually no, your initial version was not formatted correctly. Spaces were not even, thus making it hard to read...  Did you get your answer? Were you able to use the right and left join like loki9 suggested?

Comment: hey CodeGodie.. no it dint seem to get rid of the redundant data sent back...which i placed in tabular form

Comment: in order to further help you out, you have to provide what your tables look like, what you're currently getting in your results, and what you actually want. Once you give is this information, we will be able to create a good query.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your query like this, I used left join and right join..

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->join('order_detail', 'orders.serial = order_detail.orderid', 'left');
$this->db->join('customers', 'orders.customerid = customers.serial', 'right');
$this->db->order_by('date','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
return $result;
```